# raise self._value NameError: name 'global_df' is not defined

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing, pool, nameerror

when I tried to execute this code. I receive the error related to global_df is not defined. I am new to multiprocessing. The main problem is with the stock_sample where the variables such as global_df, target,global_ems, and global_ci are not defined.
I am not sure how can i resolve this error.
I tried to make global_df as global global_df But it didn't resolve the error.

The code is taken from https://github.com/BUAA-WJR/PriceGraph/blob/master/code/dataset.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import os
import sys
import math
import json
import pickle
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from multiprocessing import Pool


PWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


def load_stock(s):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Desktop\\Blockchain\\PriceGraph-master\\PriceGraph-master\\data\\data', s), index_col=0)
    df.set_index(df.index.astype('str'), inplace=True)
    return df


def load_ci(f, xi='close'):
    with open(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Desktop\\Blockchain\\PriceGraph-master\\PriceGraph-master\\code\\CI', xi, '%s.json' % f[:-4])) as fp:
        return json.load(fp)


def load_embedding(f, xi='close', ti=None):
    with open(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Desktop\\Blockchain\\PriceGraph-master\\PriceGraph-master\\Struc2vec', xi, '%s.json' % f[:-4])) as fp:
        j = json.load(fp)
    if ti is not None:
        return {d: j[d] for d in ti if d in j}
    return j


def z_score(df):
    return (df - df.mean()) / df.std()


def stock_sample(input_):
    s, d = input_
    T = 20
    df = global_df[s]
    if d not in df.index:
        return
    iloc = list(df.index).index(d) + 1
    if iloc < T:  # not enough history data
        return
    xss = {}
    for xi in x_column:
        # t
        t = 1 if df.iloc[iloc+target-1,:][xi] > df.loc[d, xi] else 0
        # y
        y = df.iloc[iloc-T:iloc][xi].copy()
        yz = np.array(z_score(y))
        if np.isnan(yz).any():
            return
        # ems
        ems = global_ems[s][xi]
        if d not in ems:
            return
        keys = ['%s' % i for i in range(T)]
        emd = np.array([ems[d][k] for k in keys])
        if len(emd) < T:
            return
        # ci
        cis = global_ci[s][xi]
        if d not in cis:
            return
        cid = cis[d]
        cid = [cid[str(i)] for i in range(T)]
        ciz = np.array(z_score(np.array(cid)))
        if np.isnan(ciz).any():
            ciz = np.array(cid)
        xss['%s_ems' % xi] = emd
        xss['%s_ys' % xi] = yz
        xss['%s_cis' % xi] = ciz
        xss['%s_t' % xi] = t
    return s, d, \
           xss['close_t'], xss['close_ems'], xss['close_ys'], xss['close_cis'], \
           xss['open_t'], xss['open_ems'], xss['open_ys'], xss['open_cis'], \
           xss['high_t'], xss['high_ems'], xss['high_ys'], xss['high_cis'], \
           xss['low_t'], xss['low_ems'], xss['low_ys'], xss['low_cis'], \
           xss['vol_t'], xss['vol_ems'], xss['vol_ys'], xss['vol_cis'], \
           xss['amount_t'], xss['amount_ems'], xss['amount_ys'], xss['amount_cis']


def sample_by_dates(dates):
    files = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Desktop\\Blockchain\\PriceGraph-master\\PriceGraph-master\\data\\data')
    fds = [(f, d) for d in dates for f in files]
    pool = Pool()
    samples = pool.map(stock_sample, fds)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    samples = filter(lambda s: s is not None, samples)
    stocks, days, \
    close_t, close_ems, close_ys, close_cis, \
    open_t, open_ems, open_ys, open_cis, \
    high_t, high_ems, high_ys, high_cis, \
    low_t, low_ems, low_ys, low_cis, \
    vol_t, vol_ems, vol_ys, vol_cis, \
    amount_t, amount_ems, amount_ys, amount_cis = zip(*samples)
    return {'stock': np.array(stocks), 'day': np.array(days),
            'close_t': np.array(close_t), 'close_ems': np.array(close_ems), 'close_ys': np.array(close_ys), 'close_cis': np.array(close_cis),
            'open_t': np.array(open_t), 'open_ems': np.array(open_ems), 'open_ys': np.array(open_ys), 'open_cis': np.array(open_cis),
            'high_t': np.array(high_t), 'high_ems': np.array(high_ems), 'high_ys': np.array(high_ys), 'high_cis': np.array(high_cis),
            'low_t': np.array(low_t), 'low_ems': np.array(low_ems), 'low_ys': np.array(low_ys), 'low_cis': np.array(low_cis),
            'vol_t': np.array(vol_t), 'vol_ems': np.array(vol_ems), 'vol_ys': np.array(vol_ys), 'vol_cis': np.array(vol_cis),
            'amount_t': np.array(amount_t), 'amount_ems': np.array(amount_ems), 'amount_ys': np.array(amount_ys), 'amount_cis': np.array(amount_cis),
            }


def generate_data_year(year):
    global global_ems
    start_date = datetime(year, 1, 1)
    days = [(start_date+timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y%m%d') for i in range(366)]
    days = [d for d in days if '%s0101' % year <= d <= '%s1231' % year]
    global_ems = {f: {xc: load_embedding(f, xc, days) for xc in x_column} for f in files}
    dataset = sample_by_dates(days)
    with open(os.path.join('dataset', '%s.pickle' % year), 'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(dataset, fp)


def generate_data_season(year, season):
    global global_ems
    start_date = datetime(year, sm, 1)
    days = [(start_date+timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y%m%d') for i in range(366)]
    sm, em = str((season - 1) * 3 + 1).zfill(2), str(season * 3).zfill(2)
    days = [d for d in days if '%s%s01' % (year, sm) <= d <= '%s%s31' % (year, em)]
    global_ems = {f: {xc: load_embedding(f, xc, days) for xc in x_column} for f in files}
    dataset = sample_by_dates(days)
    with open(os.path.join('dataset', '%s_S%s.pickle' % (year, season)), 'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(dataset, fp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Desktop\\Blockchain\\PriceGraph-master\\PriceGraph-master\\data\\data')
    if not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Desktop\\Blockchain\\PriceGraph-master\\PriceGraph-master\\dataset'):
        os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Desktop\\Blockchain\\PriceGraph-master\\PriceGraph-master\\dataset')
    x_column = ['close', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'vol', 'amount']
    y_column = 'close'
    target = 1
    global_ems = None
    global_df = {f: load_stock(f) for f in files}
    global_ci = {f: {xc: load_ci(f, xc) for xc in x_column} for f in files}
    for y in range(2018, 2009, -1):
        print(y)
        generate_data_year(y)
    for m in range(1, 5):
        print(m)
        generate_data_season(2019, m)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow usually likes if you provide a minimal, reproducible example. We don't want to download all your csvs to reproduce part of your code.

It should look something like this

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def print_globals(text):
    print(f"{text} {global_var}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global_var = 1
    Pool().map(print_globals, ["hi"])
```

This will often also give you insight on why the issue occurs.

In your case that would be because the variables aren't in  the scope of the processes you run. Instead you should pass the variables required to the functions that need it. Using global variables is considered bad practice, as you easily lose sight of where you use/change it.

A better version would be:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def print_globals(text, global_var):
    print(f"{text} {global_var}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global_var = 1
    Pool().starmap(print_globals, [("hi", global_var)])
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. Thanks for your suggestion I was new to StackOverflow I will be careful in future by  providing the minimal codes for the problems to understand better.